# How to make a patch ignore the file index using "git apply"?

Tags: git, command, git-index, git-apply

I'm trying to apply a .patch file to my source, but it fails because my file index (10655) is older than the patch index (10755).

Now I know that I can just modify the patch's file index but I would like to know if there is any way using git to make a patch ignore the file index differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find the `patch` application less strict about what it is applying to.  IE, just run 'patch -p0 < file' and it should apply it and then you can commit it.

The downside is that you'll loose the authoring information, etc, so you might want to use --author along with the commit.

Answer (score 0):

I am needing the same thing, but for a different reason: I need to patch files that are stored in Git LFS which [causes trouble](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1306) to `git apply` because `git apply` uses the **index** state of the file (the LFS hash) instead of the **workspace** state (i.e. the state on the filesystem).

I also cannot use `patch` because I also need the method to support git binary diffs, on which `patch` [fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432309/git-binary-diffs-are-not-supported-error-upon-running-patch-p1-patch-file) with "git binary diffs are not supported". So the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172352/4669135) does not work for me.

I wish there was an option to `git apply` that would allow cleanly and easily ignoring the git repo, but I found none in my version of git (2.30.2).

## First solution (hackish)

The idea is to disable git, temporarily.

```
mv .git .git-hidden-to-git-apply
git apply stuff.patch
mv .git-hidden-to-git-apply .git
```

## Second solution (also hackish)

The idea is to run `git apply` from outside of the git repo.

```
cd ..
git apply stuff.patch --directory=my_git_repo --unsafe-paths
cd my_git_repo
```